# Gnome screencast not working

Tags: gnome, 19.04, 19.10, screencast

I'm trying to use the Gnome in-built screen recorder. The shortcut key, according to numerous sites is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>. However it is not working. No screen recording is started when I press the key combination and no red mark in the status bar.

I tried this both on Wayland and Xorg to no avail.

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

From **Szunti**'s answer in https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=120134

> Screencast use gstreamer, and vp8 encoder by default

I installed `gstramer` package using `pacman -S gstreamer` in my arch linux.
You can take a look at beginning of https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/installing/on-linux.html?gi-language=c and see how to install in **Ubuntu / Debian** and **Fedora**.